# How do i encode any character in my search input in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, encoding, urlencode

I am not sure if i understand how this exactly works, i am trying to percent encode the user input because letters like ø,æ,å and backspace is frequently used for the input. This is my attempt so far.

```
    func SearchData(){
        let name = searchText
        // updating page every time...
        let encode = name.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
        let url = "http://xmlopen.rejseplanen.dk/bin/rest.exe/location?input=\(String(describing: encode))&format=json"
        print(url)
        self.vm.SearchData(url: url)
    }
    
}
```

**Final solution that was made by vadians answer below.**

```
   func searchData(){
        // updating page every time...
        let encode = searchText.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
        let url = "http://xmlopen.rejseplanen.dk/bin/rest.exe/location?input=\(encode)&format=json"
        print(url)
        self.vm.searchData(url: url)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are misusing `String(describing`. It doesn't fix a failed percent encoding.

Second of all the percent encoding is related to the `query` portion of the URL, not to the `host`.

Third of all name functions with starting lowercase letter

Force unwrapping the encoded string is safe because the content of a search field is always in the range of encodable characters.

```
func searchData(){
    // updating page every time...
    let encode = searchText.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
    let url = "http://xmlopen.rejseplanen.dk/bin/rest.exe/location?input=\(encode))&format=json"
    print(url)
    self.vm.SearchData(url: url)
}
```

A suitable alternative is `URLComponents` and `URLQueryItem` which encodes the string properly.

Comment: It didn't work when force unwrapping like that, so i tried this `guard let encode = searchText.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) else { return }`
and it worked.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, `guard` must be deleted.